# Plotting Numerical Integration of Multiple Variables

Tags: plotting, numerical-integration

I am trying to plot a multiple variable integral. But somehow this is not working. This is my code.

```
a = 5;
b = .1;
f = (1 + Exp[(k - a)]);
B = f*(1/(z - (q^2 + k*q*x) + I*b) + 
    1/(z - (q^2 - k*q*x) + I*b));
ListContourPlot[
NIntegrate[Re[B], {x, -1, 1}, {k, -a, a}], {z, 0, 5, 
 1}, {q, 0, 5, 1}]
```

I shall be more interested in keeping the steps size of z and q fixed. Any help will be highly appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
a = 5; b = .1; f = (1 + Exp[(k - a)]);
g[x_] := f*(1/(z - (q^2 + k*q*x) + I*b) + 1/(z - (q^2 - k*q*x) + I*b));
ListContourPlot[Table[NIntegrate[Re[g[x]], {x, -1, 1}, {k, -a, a}], {z, 0, 5, 1},{q,0, 5, 1}]]
```

It seems your function is singular at the origin and other points of (z,q), so you may get to see warnings.

Comment: Is there any way to deal with these singularities in mathematica? Because i am seeing warning sign even at z and q not equal to zero.

Comment: @HazoorImran, Sorry Not a much idea about it.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to do the `x` integration exactly. To do so, I will use [`ComplexExpand`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ComplexExpand) and exact values:

```
a = 5;
b = 1/10;
g[x_] = ComplexExpand @ Re[(1/(z-(q^2+k q x) + b I) + 1/(z-(q^2-k q x) + b I))];

h[k_, q_, z_] = Integrate[
    FullSimplify[g[x]],
    {x, -1, 1},
    Assumptions -> (q | k | z) \[Element] Reals
]
```

> -(Log[(1 + 100 (-q (k + q) + z)^2)/(1 + 100 ((k - q) q + z)^2)]/(k q))

Then, the second integral can be done numerically without messages:

```
int[q_?NumericQ, z_] := NIntegrate[h[k, q, z] (1 + Exp[k - a]), {k, -a, a}]
```

Visualization:

```
ContourPlot[int[q, z], {q, 0, 5}, {z, 0, 5}]
```

[image]